# Attributed string cutting and displaying single word into two lines on UILabel

Tags: swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm creating attributed text using following attributes,

```
func attributedString(font: UIFont, contentColor: UIColor, alignment: NSTextAlignment) -> NSAttributedString {

    let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0.6
    paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.8
    paragraphStyle.alignment = alignment
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    let lineSpacingAttribute: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle, NSAttributedStringKey.font: font, NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: contentColor]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: lineSpacingAttribute)

    return attributedString
}
```

I'm displaying this text on `UILabel` inside a custom `tableViewCell`. But, it is cutting a single word into two (cutting last letter of a word and displaying it on next line). I've set the `numberOfLines` to zero, and `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` for label. And I'm using a custom font.

[image]

This problem is happening on small screens only, iPhone SE and iPhone 5S simulators. But, on other simulators it is displaying correctly. Could you please help me to figure out what is wrong in this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From **Apple doc:**

> var preferredMaxLayoutWidth: CGFloat
>
> This property affects the size of the label when layout constraints are applied to it. During layout, if the text extends beyond the width specified by this property, the additional text flows to one or more new lines, increasing the height of the label.

Depending on your text you can use the **adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth** property with the **minimumScaleFactor** property

Comment: Thanks @Francesco. But I need consistent font size throughout the view. So, I can't resize text.

Comment: You are welcome, so you have to check your label width :/